# Automate inserting stylesheet into HTML

Tags: html, css, automation, gulp

How do I automate turning something like ...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

... into something like ...

```
<style>
    /* lotsa CSS rules */
</style>
```

... in an HTML document?

I currently do it manually. I also use a [postCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) with a bunch of plugins. So, I start with a separate CSS file and I use a `link` tag initially. When I'm done working on the CSS, I comment out the `link` tag and add a `style` tag and copy all of the CSS into the document. Vim makes this a little easier:

```
:read css/main.css
```

I already use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for automating some of my workflow, so I prefer a solution that can be easily integrated with that.

Gulp has been a great benefit for me, but I might not understand enough about how it works. I tried searching the plugins and I found too many that look like they'll do what I want. Some of them seem to process the CSS and HTML to add `style` tags to the individual elements, which is not what I want.

- [gulp-smoosher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-smoosher/)
- [gulp-css-inliner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-css-inliner/)
- [gulp-inline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline/)

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you even interested in doing this? What's the benefit of putting the CSS directly inside the `<style>` tag when you can just link it like it was originally?

Comment: @JamesScottTayler to eliminate [Render blocking CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css?hl=en) and [Minimize HTTP Requests](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

Comment: Ah ok. Those seem like some pretty good reasons. Wasn't aware of them, thanks for the info. Looking at gulp-smoosher isn't that what you are wanting to achieve? It says it takes a traditionally linked css file and inlines the contents of the css file into the `<style></style>` tag in the `<head></head>` section of the document. Did you give it a try? Failing that i'd just write bash one-liner with `grep` and `sed` to do it, but these tools seem much more appropriate.

Comment: Smoosher looked like the right one to me too, but so did a few others. I tried smoosher and it works, but I ran into [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34846749/2948042), but I'm probably misunderstanding something about how Gulp works internally. I was hoping for an answer from someone with experience to say something like "this is how I do it".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) has a task for this. Check out the github repo [here](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline).

Install the plugin:

```
npm install grunt-inline --save-dev
```

Enable the plugin inside your gruntfile:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-inline');
```

> In your project's Gruntfile, add a section named inline to the data object passed into grunt.initConfig().

```
grunt.initConfig({
  inline: {
    dist: {
     src: 'src/index.html',
    dest: 'dist/index.html'
   }
  }
})
```

Which should turn this:

```
<link href="css/style.css?__inline=true" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Into this:

```
<style>
    /* contents of css/style.css */
</style>`
```

Comment: This would probably do it, but I'm really hoping for a Gulp solution. There has been so much time lost to learning and setting up the build environment. I'd write that bash code before switching again for this one bit of functionality. I thought web development was supposed to be easier these days :]

Comment: It's supposed to be easier if you're using [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) but it's that initial learning curve that slows things down.